# Aborting AWS operations/ installing Anaconda with numbapro

Tags: amazon-web-services, anaconda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, numba-pro

Two part question, would really appreciate help on either part. I'm attempting to install Anaconda followed by numbapro on AWS EB. My options.config in .ebextensions looks like this:

```
commands:
 00_download_conda:
 command: 'wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh'
 test: test ! -d /anaconda
01_install_conda:
 command: 'bash Anaconda2-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh'
 command: echo 'Finished installing Anaconda'
 test: test ! -d /anaconda
02_install_cuda:
 command: 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda2/bin'
 command: echo 'About to install numbapro'
 command: 'conda install -c anaconda numbapro'
```

Whenever I attempt to deploy this I run into a timeout and when I try and manually stop the current processes from the console I get an error saying that the environment is not in a state where I can abort the current operation or view any log files.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

First, you need to make sure that you're properly indenting your YAML file, as YAML is sensitive to whitespace. Your file should look like this:

```
commands:
  00_download_conda: 
    command: 'wget http://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh'
    test: test ! -d /anaconda
  01_install_conda:
    command: 'bash Anaconda2-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh'
    ...
```

Next, you can only have one `command:` entry per command. The `echo` commands aren't particularly valuable, as you can see what commands are being executed by looking at `/var/log/eb-activity.log`. You can also combine the `export PATH` line with `conda install` something like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda2/bin conda install -c anaconda numbapro
```

If you're still having trouble after you clear up those items, check (or post here) `eb-activity.log` to see what's going on.

Refer to [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) for more details.